# Shared Dataset is not supported with sql server 2012 reporting services

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008

I am trying to deploy the shared dataset in Visual Studio 2010 solution to Sql server 2012 reporting services. But always getting the below error:

> The feature: "Shared dataset" is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what version of SQL Server you're using.

If it's Express Edition Advanced or Workgroup or Web edition, I think it's not supported.

[www.katieandemil.com](http://www.katieandemil.com/ssrs-the-feature-shared-dataset-is-not-supported-in-this-edition-of-reporting-services)

Answer (score 2):

Shared dataset are absent in express, web & workgroup versions [see msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365156.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to the SQL BI tools.  After a couple of days of setting up I hit this same problem.  And saw where the Express Edition (which is what I'm using) doesn't support shared datasets.   So I changed my test reports to use embedded data sets & reports are now able to deploy.